# Maven packaging: mvn deploy using .zip rather than .rar

Tags: maven, pom.xml, archiva

I'm deploying from a Jenkins job, using the Maven "deploy" target, to an Archiva repository.

Currently I'm not using other targets and I create the pom.xml just in order to pack and deploy the files.

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>group_continuous</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>60-r12345-v0.0.01</version>
  <packaging>rar</packaging>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>repo_continuous</id>
      <name>Continuous</name>
      <url>http://10.142.255.179:8080/repository/repo_continuous/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

In order to have it work I just put all the required files in the folder

```
target/MyArtifactId-60-r12345-v0.0.01/*
```

before calling

```
mvn deploy
```

I know that I can use for the purpose the command

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
```

And use a plugin to just create the .zip archive but I wonder if there's a way to just add the .zip support in order to have the exact same functionality of the .rar

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at the [maven-rar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/) ?

Comment: No but I don't understand the reason since .rar already works fine while I was hoping for .zip support

Comment: I would say it makes the handling easier http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/examples/include-extra-files.html